# How to access files from assets folder in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have some images and style sheets files inside assets folder in angular 2 app but how to access those files and images in main index.html file?

Comment: share your code with us

Comment: Are you using webpack or anything similar?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to put your files and use the relative path from the assets folder.

For example if i put a css file in `src/assets/css/myfile.css`, then I have to access it like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/myfile.css">
```

Comment: What about files that I might want to access in the component? For instance, static JSON files

Comment: For json-Files you can take a look here: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-angular/

Answer (score 4):

**Directly refer assets folder and inside images working**

```
 <img src="/assets/img_avatar.png" />
```

Answer (score -3):

It's one step behind /app. So if you are inside app/components/page/page.css, reference url(/assets/images/logo.png)

Comment: It isn't a good practice to use relative paths. Is there a simpler way to this? these frameworks are supposed to make things easier. Apparently, they are not!

Comment: @Murray When you move your component to another directory (which has a different depth) the path will be broken.